# Symfony Formbuilder get pathInfo

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

Is there a way to return the pathInfo or URL of the page inside the buildForm Function?

```
class RoomType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

 VarDumper::dump($builder->getRequestHandler());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only if you have the request object. One option would be to pass the request when you construct the form.

Your controller action

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RoomType($request), new Room());
```

Your form type class

```
class RoomType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        VarDumper::dump($this->request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly and don't forget to add use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Comment: A second approach is to create your form type as a service(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service) and then inject the request stack (http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack).  Bit more work but the service approach means you don't have to remember to inject the request when you create the form.  It also means you can use the form type in a nested form.